# How we can use goTo(slidenumber) in nz-carousel? If I wanted to go at specific slide number directly

Tags: typescript, carousel, angular8, ng-zorro-antd

Please find ng-zorro link for reference.
https://ng.ant.design/components/carousel/en#header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ViewChild` to get the component instance and use the instance methods.

```
  index = 0;

  @ViewChild(NzCarouselComponent, { static: false }) myCarousel: NzCarouselComponent;

  goTo() {
    this.myCarousel.goTo(Number(this.index));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rsuzz?file=src/app/app.component.ts